# How to prove $\int_0^1 \frac{\arctan( a x)}{x \sqrt{1 - x^2}} dx = \frac{\pi}{2} \ln (a + \sqrt{1 + a^2})$?

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals

I found the integral

$$\int_0^1 \frac{\arctan( a x)}{x \sqrt{1 - x^2}} dx = \frac{\pi}{2} \ln (a + \sqrt{1 + a^2})$$

in Gradshteyn and Ryzhik book and I try to solve it, but can't.

Taking the derivative, you get

$$\int_0^1 \frac{1}{(1 + a^2 x^2) \sqrt{1 - x^2}} dx = \frac{\pi}{2} \frac{1}{\sqrt{1 + a^2}}$$,

but this integral doesn't seem any easier. Have hints? Highschool methods would be best for me.

Comment: You could let $a=\tan\theta$ next.

Comment: Almost a duplicate: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/834205/calculate-int-01-frac-arctanxx-sqrt1-x2dx Felix Marin's answer does address your question, though.

Comment: @RandomVariable Thanks for mention my answer.

Answer (score 6):

$$\large I(\alpha)=\int_0^1 \frac{\text{arctan }(\alpha x)}{x\sqrt{1-x^2}}$$
$$\large I'(\alpha)=\frac{\pi}{2}\frac{1}{\sqrt{1+\alpha^2}}$$
as per your question
$$ I(\alpha)=\frac{\pi}{2}\int\frac{1}{\sqrt{1+\alpha^2}}$$
$$ I(\alpha)=\frac{\pi}{2}\int\frac{\cosh\theta}{\sqrt{1+\sinh\theta^2}}$$
$$ I(\alpha)=\frac{\pi}{2}\int\frac{1}{1}$$
$$ I(\alpha)=\frac{\pi}{2}\theta+C$$
$$ I(\alpha)=\frac{\pi}{2}\text{arcsinh } \alpha+C$$
Now we find $C$.
$$ I(0)=\int_0^1 \frac{0}{x\sqrt{1-x^2}}=0=\frac{\pi}2 \times 0 +C$$
Therefore $C=0,$ and therefore 
$$ I(\alpha)=\frac\pi 2 \text{arcsinh } \alpha$$
$$ \large I(\alpha)=\frac\pi 2 (\log[\alpha+\sqrt{\alpha^2+1}])$$

Comment: Explanations:

1,2: Original Integral and Derivative

3:Integration

4: $\alpha=\sinh(\theta)$

5: $1+\sinh^2(\theta)=\cosh^2(\theta)$

6:$\int 1$

7: Back Substitution

8: Finding constant

9: $C=0$

10: Alternate form of arcsinh